# How can I get center position of my div elements?

Tags: html, center, responsive

I can't get center position of my div elements. Could you help me please? I need that my div would be responsive on mobile too. My code

'

```
            <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

                  <div class="item"><img src="images/quote.png"/><br/> TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
                  <div class="item"><img src="images/quote.png"/><br/> TEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TEST</div>
                  <div class="item"><img src="images/quote.png"/><br/> TEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TEST</div>

            </div>

        </div>'
```

`#owl-demo .item{

```
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin:   5px;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;


}

#owl-demo{

     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place `position:relative;` on parent, then on child (ie `#owl-demo`):

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

It will be vertically and horizontally no matter what.

Another way is flexbox:

```
.mainflex {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

`.mainflex` would be the parent element only, there's no need to adjust the child. David reminded me, If you don't want them side-by-side add `flex-direction: column;`.

#### SNIPPET 1

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  }
#owl-demo .item {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
#owl-demo {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
`
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=1" />
    <br/>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=2" />
    <br/>TEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TEST</div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=3" />
    <br/>TEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TESTTEST TEST TEST</div>

</div>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
htmal,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
#mainFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main id='mainFlex'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</main>
```

Comment: shouldn't children have 100% width so that they don't float side-by-side?
when using `display: flex;` of course.

Comment: I'll make a demo and we shall see.;)

Comment: I forgot to add `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`, but yeah it works see update.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I forgot that there is a flex-direction `column` ... I'm always using `row`, I'm getting used to it..